# How to prove $(A \setminus B) \times C = (A \times C) \setminus (B \times C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $$(A \setminus B) \times C = (A \times C) \setminus (B \times C)$$

And if there is any tutorial for this kind of things because I don't know how to search on the internet for this kind of examples, because I don't know whats the name (term)!

In my language its called something like this: **numbers theory**.

Comment: This is strange. I read the equation as an equation of sets, you call it "numbers theory" and the tag says (said) "functional-equations".

Comment: @K.Stm. please ignore the tag because I didnt know how to tag it! my fault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have to prove the equality of two sets, say $X=Y$, there are (more than) two ways to go about it.

1. **Show $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$**.  This way is useful when you can't see by the way they're written that they have the same elements. It's also useful when one is obviously a subset of the other.
2. **Write down their elements.** This way is useful when the expression you're given for the sets hint at an easy expression in [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation), for instance.

Here I'd use (2) because the expressions are quite similar.

By definition,
$$(A \setminus B) \times C = \{ (a,c)\, :\, a \in A,\ a \not \in B\ \text{and}\ c \in C \}$$
and
$$(A \times C) \setminus (B \times C) = \{ (a,c)\, :\, (a,c) \in A \times C\ \text{and}\ (a,c) \not \in B \times C \}$$

How might you argue from here that the expressions refer to the same set?

Regarding your second question: in English, this area of mathematics is called *set theory* or, more specifically, *elementary set theory* or *naïve set theory*.